# Clustered standard errors with panel data in survregbayes

Tags: r, survival-analysis, standard-error

I'm currently working with a panel dataset containing information on 7903 cities from 2012 to 2022. My focus is on studying the digitalization of city administrations using survival models. Specifically, I've defined `t0` to mark the beginning of the period, and `t2` for the end of the period corresponding to either the year of digitalization (if the event occurred) or the end of the panel. The binary variable `treat_v` indicates whether the event was realized. Additionally, the variable `PRO_COM` serves as a unique identifier for cities. My independent variables include total population, average income, and administration software expenditure.

My dataset looks like:

```
  PRO_COM  year treat_v    t0    t2 total_ln Avg_income_ln software_ln
     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
 1    1001  2012       0     0     1     7.88          9.95        13.6
 2    1001  2013       0     1     2     7.91          9.96         0  
 3    1001  2014       0     2     3     7.92          9.98        14.6
 4    1001  2015       0     3     4     7.90         10.0         14.0
 5    1001  2016       0     4     5     7.88         10.0         12.0
 6    1001  2017       0     5     6     7.89         10.0          0  
 7    1001  2018       0     6     7     7.89         10.0          0  
 8    1001  2019       0     7     8     7.88         10.0          0  
 9    1001  2020       1     8     9     7.87         10.0          0  
10    1002  2012       0     0     1     8.26          9.87        14.0
11    1002  2013       0     1     2     8.26          9.88        13.4
12    1002  2014       0     2     3     8.24          9.88        12.8
```

I need to use an accelerated failure time model and a spatial accelerated failure time model. I'm employing the `survregbayes` function from the `spBayesSurv` package. Is there a way to implement robust standard errors clustered by city in this model with this function? Here's the code I've used:

```
install.packages('spBayesSurv')
library(spBayesSurv)
mcmc <- list(nburn = 5000, nsave = 10000, nskip = 5, ndisplay= 2000)
prior <- list(maxL = 15)

res_prova <- survregbayes(Surv(t0, t2, treat_v) ~ total_ln + Avg_income_ln + software_ln
                      , data=df_prova, 
                      survmodel="AFT", dist="lognormal",InitParamMCMC=T, mcmc=mcmc,prior=prior)
summary.survregbayes(res_prova)
```

Any guidance on implementing robust standard errors clustered by city in this model would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here there is a reproducible example of my dataset:

```
df_prova <- structure(list(PRO_COM = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 
1002, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1006, 
1006, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1011, 1011, 1011, 
1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1020, 1020, 1020, 1020, 1020, 1020, 
1020, 1020, 1020, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1022, 1022, 
1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1028, 1028, 1028, 1028, 
1028, 1028, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 1029, 
1029, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 1030, 
1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1034, 1034, 
1034, 1034, 1034, 1034, 1034, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
1038, 1038, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1054, 
1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 2049, 2049, 2049, 
2049, 2049, 2049, 2049, 2049, 2049, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 
1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 4056, 4056, 4056, 4056, 4056, 4056, 
4056, 4056, 4056, 4056, 6124, 6124, 6124, 6124, 6124, 6124, 6124, 
6124, 6124, 6124), year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021), treat_v = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), t0 = c(0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9), t2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), total_ln = c(7.88495294575981, 
7.90912218321141, 7.91862865334224, 7.90137735379262, 7.88004820097158, 
7.88645727097769, 7.88532923927319, 7.87625888230323, 7.87131120332341, 
8.25790419346567, 8.25660734462616, 8.24038511551633, 8.24222989137223, 
8.23244015847034, 8.22309055116153, 8.20821938349683, 8.19229373114764, 
8.18813341451048, 7.49942329059223, 7.49831587076698, 7.49164547360513, 
7.46965417293213, 7.454719949364, 7.43897159239586, 7.42714413340862, 
7.40367029001237, 7.40488757561612, 8.75557997214314, 8.76092337633884, 
8.76295892076673, 8.76201995356159, 8.76201995356159, 8.76514642163902, 
8.76592651372944, 8.7649903301691, 8.7681075396758, 6.7719355558396, 
6.76734312526539, 6.78784498230958, 6.79234442747081, 6.78784498230958, 
6.78671695060508, 6.76272950693188, 6.75925527066369, 8.10167774745457, 
8.0925452638913, 8.09833884618906, 8.08548677210285, 8.0702808933939, 
8.07464907506665, 8.07837810362652, 8.07246736935477, 8.06808962627824, 
8.08733292647335, 8.07868822922987, 8.0805469658245, 8.07496035911586, 
8.07090608878782, 8.05737748855799, 8.0507033814703, 8.0519780789023, 
9.80604009037016, 9.80697665215529, 9.81022028456569, 9.80989090379854, 
9.80592984894132, 9.80388818731337, 9.79701530802561, 9.51811914612709, 
9.51826615090501, 9.50509735809993, 9.50479942870699, 9.50248746138712, 
9.35625724687634, 6.31716468674728, 6.33859407820318, 6.32256523992728, 
6.33327962813969, 6.3261494731551, 6.36647044773144, 6.37331978957701, 
6.36818718635049, 6.37672694789863, 6.38350663488401, 8.21878715560148, 
8.21256839823415, 8.21148291644507, 8.20985248130127, 8.21121136179302, 
8.21229713822977, 8.19918935907807, 8.19726337141434, 8.18757739559151, 
8.18590748148232, 6.73340189183736, 6.73221070646721, 6.71659477352098, 
6.69332366826995, 6.68710860786651, 6.66949808985788, 6.68710860786651, 
6.66185474054531, 6.67203294546107, 9.04168500594604, 9.05028898382796, 
9.05415428878685, 9.06056344665796, 9.05777177333158, 9.05800471067248, 
9.05963375455148, 9.05380351415596, 9.05450494041805, 9.05310159554969, 
9.05122740031911, 9.05648964715792, 9.05555615817532, 9.05286751315162, 
9.06508335931904, 7.35436233042148, 7.37086016653672, 7.35564110297425, 
7.34987370473834, 7.33236920592906, 7.33367639565768, 7.3356339819272, 
7.3304052118444, 6.33150184989369, 6.33505425149806, 6.34738920965601, 
6.32793678372919, 6.34035930372775, 6.35088571671474, 6.3456363608286, 
6.37331978957701, 6.38687931936265, 8.99044155082686, 8.98582087448204, 
8.97233695775495, 8.97233695775495, 8.962391701743, 8.96200720958831, 
8.95789673495042, 8.95260537589235, 8.95480275285097, 6.86797440897029, 
6.8596149036542, 6.87005341179813, 6.83947643822884, 6.80682936039218, 
6.8001700683022, 6.82762923450285, 6.81673588059497, 6.81892406527552, 
6.85329909318608, 6.77878489768518, 6.8001700683022, 6.79570577517351, 
6.8001700683022, 6.80461452006262, 6.78445706263764, 6.75460409948796, 
6.71417052990947, 6.7286286130847, 6.72383244082121, 5.4553211153577, 
5.45958551414416, 5.45958551414416, 5.48893772615669, 5.45958551414416, 
5.4380793089232, 5.37063802812766, 5.28826703069454, 5.29831736654804, 
5.31811999384422), Avg_income_ln = c(9.95100918119281, 9.95823055302686, 
9.98051362913682, 10.0147662587243, 10.0278481007699, 10.0207687542477, 
10.0270911612452, 10.0330884347624, 10.0182449760809, 9.87347148493794, 
9.87561183232373, 9.88441973683242, 9.92989801004952, 9.93404314940026, 
9.91981091852989, 9.95102684439529, 9.94812688711294, 9.93168066211429, 
9.86416456839784, 9.86945437321638, 9.8786032427481, 9.90554554577413, 
9.90538663594792, 9.92630779643173, 9.98743798079886, 9.95116613437205, 
9.92429761999365, 10.0791467276647, 10.0785916165192, 10.0979747153919, 
10.1093433768296, 10.1243592564318, 10.1313177524273, 10.1421991535854, 
10.1472236062147, 10.1449984323863, 9.69115927507824, 9.71567911722924, 
9.69160543576198, 9.71492718807839, 9.71905607124579, 9.71676743188018, 
9.73680470874232, 9.76639980510036, 9.92603914306631, 9.94982592757546, 
9.93604995592034, 9.94077330019114, 9.92289898150387, 9.9297250950782, 
9.95786635866039, 9.94516720091473, 9.94471127303208, 9.98806441661829, 
10.0060145152037, 10.0188792059974, 10.0196752619576, 10.0391642554939, 
10.0549671389672, 10.0628991405105, 10.0664813284644, 9.91360955401906, 
9.91351724905354, 9.92354149929004, 9.93975675111295, 9.94835886993867, 
9.94777943409724, 9.9610919946104, 9.94103238656982, 9.95398197956198, 
9.96272563160125, 9.99133830689192, 9.99197673221995, 9.98239900872108, 
9.79889084129117, 9.82357613323638, 9.81960720165952, 9.84084181716343, 
9.83157910177803, 9.81202650121668, 9.82928231359217, 9.86134156493655, 
9.88703823704679, 9.94910113054451, 9.87753724879351, 9.89724249523534, 
9.90607947398146, 9.90519143546865, 9.9142315765518, 9.91808978798171, 
9.9138858431683, 9.96099551419382, 9.92927613508482, 9.97428918701486, 
9.89007659776826, 9.86333699424153, 9.9545987455228, 9.9208273973496, 
9.90358301867181, 9.91834450300624, 9.94004379148733, 9.97890193608502, 
9.91343037983815, 9.87106393853391, 9.89693775599761, 9.90776930489766, 
9.92985290969328, 9.92667574440502, 9.94548806196369, 9.9558504170754, 
10.0045461815298, 10.0040571381268, 10.0066109610899, 10.0315316097753, 
10.0508425375385, 10.0548054946526, 10.0803418749731, 10.0722735726998, 
9.86344913382924, 9.8822058423329, 9.89932760886725, 9.9186194411311, 
9.92663355064925, 9.92785383788164, 9.93416174109291, 9.93626525965158, 
9.72949831819389, 9.74745110136822, 9.76147071758372, 9.78655316657569, 
9.78027885232349, 9.77175673570384, 9.80192727580378, 9.80966626378322, 
9.80361746543969, 9.78123384047072, 9.80427963489623, 9.81036162920114, 
9.83390170021683, 9.84115273424143, 9.83480731766295, 9.8625013159703, 
9.86389768912967, 9.85485403369568, 9.90384314301659, 9.87493826296659, 
9.93999420618657, 9.9363366111413, 9.88791732224616, 9.91241093108613, 
9.93564514067879, 9.95273053800706, 9.93609430730758, 9.98596216242694, 
9.38374741621789, 9.45184851358746, 9.41579133089942, 9.4335946863867, 
9.43041070002655, 9.47186127965726, 9.50965151262306, 9.52028053328393, 
9.61666016444978, 9.601794269207, 9.92272263716164, 9.92155595175208, 
9.97346959372429, 9.97717523796906, 9.98008692406993, 9.97383699840932, 
10.0434836632773, 10.0580276164739, 10.0472839821578, 10.1340064364994
), software_ln = c(13.6312715640622, 0, 14.5906381061831, 13.9808631189336, 
11.9511868474935, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.9512740825277, 13.4135617603837, 
12.7855862943222, 14.0587139583923, 13.4916332709192, 11.5230440984914, 
0, 0, 8.86460536807578, 14.3240020597858, 14.2704684404963, 14.3539406483169, 
14.3590347100635, 14.4039570051622, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14.6899153962449, 
14.743230526571, 14.8680220129697, 14.867534606448, 14.7851149219686, 
0, 12.0118869877927, 13.0448320136652, 13.6447471477057, 12.041203898549, 
11.5870212941931, 11.8499047158951, 11.6818408931813, 11.8541506740155, 
0, 0, 0, 14.6084447007496, 14.8797266899012, 14.5808281562597, 
14.4534119062982, 14.5328790205436, 0, 0, 0, 12.4344862854999, 
15.5784594599531, 15.616244799835, 15.601877681259, 16.0261207030794, 
15.8415794079656, 13.2077554440183, 12.4772479782762, 14.1436712059748, 
16.0849414751002, 16.3584853095525, 16.3906017740141, 16.4729037534324, 
16.4527397890538, 0, 0, 15.7158535433994, 15.5645488345031, 15.7467622230442, 
16.181562254047, 15.8068244635054, 0, 13.5352952067061, 13.3630670434619, 
13.5382275605494, 13.2382690964485, 13.4455013928394, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 14.4477457004077, 14.4011337731848, 14.6907330149937, 14.4478886375212, 
14.379121212925, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.3087765521015, 13.1040384977011, 
14.059750800873, 13.7113393348177, 13.8261547074755, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 13.3480828082904, 15.2490379191216, 14.9543888466163, 15.0572692003486, 
14.2424951194326, 11.8263995454557, 12.9520233545, 14.1082376329627, 
14.2414734765094, 14.2756488089983, 14.306957012763, 14.4418494433975, 
0, 0, 0, 14.5645043756946, 13.8370029333024, 13.9564031652447, 
14.1991805350585, 14.0526209177311, 0, 0, 13.7015599192844, 12.9618729772842, 
13.0202265489677, 12.9846242876825, 13.0867589974288, 13.6406868221277, 
0, 11.5492670373727, 11.6915819803642, 0, 14.9882920311983, 14.8396647106143, 
15.0073122944249, 15.1917174613295, 15.4025151137662, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 11.2758477829995, 0, 11.2451244481116, 0, 0, 13.2746483178217, 
11.5374326945246, 0, 0, 13.2678687944066, 13.7453552253669, 12.2126807637444, 
13.5598386496419, 13.8382813249919, 0, 0, 0, 11.2009643610583, 
11.759621466942, 12.1209449478476, 13.3736869167548, 12.3430524605059, 
12.7509953018642, 13.2911690041448, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-174L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
    40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
    52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
    64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
    76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
    88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
    100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 
    110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
    120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
    130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
    140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -144L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try to `dput()` your datasets. So that people can help you easily.

Comment: Hi! Of course, I add a reproducible example of my dataset now. Thank you.

Comment: In any case I would add the results of the `cox.zph` call since we have no idea what you consider "failure". Alternatively you could send this question to the respective authors of the two packages you nominated for consideration, probably with a larger extract of your data and ask them to comment.

Comment: And furthermore I get errors in both of the calls to the later code both of them with the message: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'c_software_ln' not found". So adding only a fragment of  the data serves no purpose since it fails to deliver the results that are causing you to question validity and then demonstrates that it's not even from the same dataset that you later used with the two alternatives. Needs quite a bit iof further information to be a useful question.

Comment: HI! Thank you for your comments, edits and suggestions. I changed the dataset, so now the example is fully reproducible. I have removed the part regarding the Cox Proportional Hazard Model since it is not my problem's focus. I hope that now the question can be more useful.